# coeff output as plot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `geom_smooth(mehtod="lm")` to plot a linear regression. Now I'd like to use the coefficient and the intercept of the linear regression as title for the graph.

I used `Coeff <- coef(lm(Eo2005I ~ Eo2005P))` to find the values I needed, but `ggtitle` doesn't seem to like a `c(Coeff["Eo2005P"],Coeff["Intercept"])` input for the text. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "pasting" the individual elements of `coef` together.

```
coefftemp <- coef(lm(...))
Coeff <- paste(coefftemp[1],coefftemp[2])
```